# Best way to dismiss keyboard when tapping outside of UITextField - IOS

Tags: ios, uitextfield, swift4

I've found a few threads here about this, and some videos online about it as well, but every solution seems to have problems reported by others. The simplest solution I've found is the one below.

```
    import UIKit
```

class SignupController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

```
// Outlets
@IBOutlet weak var logoImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var nameTF: CustomTextField!
@IBOutlet weak var emailTF: CustomTextField!
@IBOutlet weak var passwordTF: CustomTextField!
@IBOutlet weak var confirmPassTF: CustomTextField!

// Actions
@IBAction func signupButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    logoImage.image = UIImage(named: "logo2")
    nameTF.delegate = self
    emailTF.delegate = self
    passwordTF.delegate = self
    confirmPassTF.delegate = self

}

// Moves to next text field each time return key is pressed
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

    if textField == nameTF {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        emailTF.becomeFirstResponder()
    } else if textField == emailTF {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        passwordTF.becomeFirstResponder()
    } else if textField == passwordTF {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        confirmPassTF.becomeFirstResponder()
    }else if textField == confirmPassTF {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
    }
    return true
}



// Dismisses keyboard when tapped
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}
```

}

It works, is very simple, but my project and coding experience are in their infancy, so I'm not sure if this is the best method simply because it's short, or if there's something I'm missing due to lack of experience/knowledge?

Anybody know of a better solution, or is this one just fine?

Comment: Note: touchesBegan won't get called if something outside of the textField has touchesEnabled or userInteractionEnabled turned off.  - The way I typically handle this is during the textFieldDidBeginEditing callback I add a full-screen invisible UIView over the whole screen then move the textField to the top of the view hierarchy in-front of that, then on the invisible UIView I have a tapGestureRecognizer to dismiss the keyboard. But I won't list that as an answer because I'm not convinced it's the best way to handle this, it's messy + moving the textField back to where it was is sloppy as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just do this:

```
class viewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

// Outlets
@IBOutlet weak var logoImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var nameTF: CustomTextField!
@IBOutlet weak var emailTF: CustomTextField!
@IBOutlet weak var passwordTF: CustomTextField!
@IBOutlet weak var confirmPassTF: CustomTextField!

// Actions
@IBAction func signupButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    logoImage.image = UIImage(named: "logo2")
    nameTF.delegate = self
    emailTF.delegate = self
    passwordTF.delegate = self
    confirmPassTF.delegate = self
    let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(dissMissKeyboard))
    view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

}
func dissMissKeyboard() {
    view.endEditing(true)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly! I must have made a mistake that first time around. Also, that code when copied in exactly to swift 4 gave me the following error "Argument of '#selector' refers to instance method 'dissMissKeyboard()' that is not exposed to Objective-C" but the suggested fix of adding "@objc" in front of the function seems to have worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Then you need to implement the gesture recognition for this . Or you can do like this :

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //Looks for single or multiple taps. 
    let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(dissMissKeyboard))

    //Uncomment the line below if you want the tap not not interfere and cancel other interactions.
    //tap.cancelsTouchesInView = false 

    view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
}

//Calls this function when the tap is recognized.

    func dissMissKeyboard() {
        //Causes the view (or one of its embedded text fields) to resign the first responder status.
        view.endEditing(true)
    }
```

Comment: Maybe I'm doing something wrong, but when I add that code into the viewDidLoad() and make the dismissKeyboard() function, the project just crashes when trying to click outside of the text field and dismiss the keyboard.

Comment: @cabyambo please update your question and put all of your code in.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use UITextField delegate method:

```
 func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        view.endEditing(true)
        return true
    }
```

or setup inputAccessoryView which have 'done' or 'exit' button.